# How To Define The Return Type In A Function With LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I would like to know how to define a returntype in a function in
following situation.

I've got a products and I was returning all information or one product at a time.

as you can see in my function defined below.

```
public static Products GetProducts(int pid) 
{
    var pro = from p in context.Products
              select p;

    if(pid > 0)
        pro =  pro.where(p => p.ProductID ==pid)

    return (Products)p;
}
```

the problem is its give me casting error. as you can see what i want to achieve is based on my parameter its give me a result set. some time bunch of products & some time single product. i m new to linq so any help would be appreciated.

The error is ***Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[TTDCore.Theatres]' to type 'TTDCore.Theatres'***

when i m binding it to gridview. here is a code

```
Products p = Class1.GetProducts(0);

GridView1.DataSource = p;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to return `IEnumerable<Product>`, which represents an *iterable* (or enumerable) of objects of type `Product`. LINQ in general is all based around this generic type, so it's generally what you want to return as a result of a query.

I believe your code should be fixed to become something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Products> GetProducts(int pid) 
{
    var pro = from p in context.Products
              select p;

    if(pid > 0)
        pro =  pro.Where(p => p.ProductID == pid)

    return pro;
}
```

Let me know if you meant something else in your question. I wasn't totally sure what precisely you were searching for.

Comment: yes this is exactly what i was looking for. just a quick one i tried this & it works fine on gridview. but if in the case of returning single record. i m doin in this way is it a right way ? 

        Products p = (Products)Class1.GetProducts(1).FirstOrDefault();

        Response.Write(p.ProductName);

its works find just wana know if its a right way. thanx for ur quick response.

Comment: Ah, good. :) And yeah, your suggested way of returning a single record should work fine. Depending on the situation, either the First/FirstOrDefault or Single/SingleOrDefault extension method is appropiate. The latter (Single) will throw an exception if there is *more* than one match, whereas the former (First) of course just returns the first, and then stops enumerating. The `OrDefault` bit just means to return the default value (null for reference types) if there are no matches, as opposed to throwing an exception.

Comment: The query could be expressed as only one expression too: from p in context.Products where p.ProductID == pid && pid > 0 select p

Answer (score 0):

I like to be explicit with Linq queries and lambdas. I suggest defining your function as List<Product> (or IEnumerable<Product>), then adding .ToList() to your where statement. I assume that the Products type is some sort of collection?

Comment: Product is Table in my sql Server Database = Entity Class in Entity Framework. what do you suggest is the best way to play with this scenario.

Comment: Well, I don't think you need to define the *return type of the function* as Products. You are specifying Products in the query, which is enough. So your return type should be an IEnumerable or List, if I understand the goal correctly. They will bind to your GridView just fine.